# waiting for many async functions execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have the promise function that execute async function in the loop few times for different data. I want to wait till all async functions will be executed and then resolve(), *(or call callback function in non-promise function)*:

```
var readFiles = ()=>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    var iterator = 0;
    var contents = {};
    for(let i in this.files){
      iterator++;
      let p = path.resolve(this.componentPath,this.files[i]);
      fs.readFile(p,{encoding:'utf8'},(err,data)=>{
        if(err){
          reject(`Could not read ${this.files[i]} file.`);
        } else {
          contents[this.files[i]] = data;
          iterator--;
          if(!iterator) resolve(contents);
        }
      });
    }
    if(!iterator) resolve(contents); //in case of !this.files.length
  });
};
```

I increase `iterator` on every loop repetition, then, in async function's callback decrease `iterator` and check if all async functions are done (iterator===0), if so - call `resolve()`.

It works great, but seems not elegant and readable. Do you know any better way for this issue?

Comment: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would be a great fit! Instead of one big promise, push individual smaller promises to an array. Then, use `Promise.all()` to wait until all the promises resolve.

Comment: I didn't know about that feature, thank you!

Comment: Note that what you are doing is exactly the right way to solve this; your coder instincts are on point. `Promise.all` will simply do it under the hood for you, keeping your code clean. Also - you might want to use `fs-extra`, a drop-in replacement for `fs`, but with promise support added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up the comment with some code and more detail!

`Promise.all()` takes an iterator, and waits for all promises to either resolve or reject. It will then return the results of all the promises. So instead of keeping track of when all promises resolve, we can create little promises and add them to an array. Then, use Promise.all() to wait for all of them to resolve.

```
const readFiles = () => {
  const promises = [];

  for(let i in files) {
    const p = path.resolve(componentPath, files[i]);

    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(p, {encoding:'utf8'}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
          reject(`Could not read ${files[i]} file.`);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    }));
  }

  return Promise.all(promises);
};

const fileContents = readFiles().then(contents => {
    console.log(contents)
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need push all the Promises into an array to then pass it as argument to `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)`

try something like this:

```js
var readFiles = () => {
  var promises = [];
  let contents = {};
  var keys_files = Object.keys(this.files);
  if (keys_files.length <= 0) {
   var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     resolve(contents);
   });
   promises.push(promise);
  }

  keys_files.forEach((key) => {
    var file = this.files[key];
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const currentPath = path.resolve(this.componentPath, file);
       fs.readFile(p,{encoding:'utf8'},(err, data) => {
         if (err) {
            return reject(`Could not read ${file} file.`);
         }

         contents[file] = data;
         resolve(contents)
       });
    });
  });

  return Promises.all(promises);
}
```

Then you should use the function like so:

```
// this will return a promise that contains an array of promises
var readAllFiles = readFiles();
// the then block only will execute if all promises were resolved if one of them were reject so all the process was rejected automatically
readAllFiles.then((promises) => {
   promises.forEach((respond) => {
      console.log(respond);
   });
}).catch((error) => error);
```

If you don't care if one of the promises was rejected, maybe you should do the following

```js
var readFiles = () => {
  var promises = [];
  let contents = {};
  var keys_files = Object.keys(this.files);
  if (keys_files.length <= 0) {
   var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     resolve(contents);
   });
   promises.push(promise);
  }

  keys_files.forEach((key) => {
    var file = this.files[key];
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const currentPath = path.resolve(this.componentPath, file);
       fs.readFile(p,{encoding:'utf8'},(err, data) => {
         // create an object with the information
         let info = { completed: true };
         if (err) {
            info.completed = false;
            info.error = err;
            return resolve(info);
         }

         info.data = data;
         contents[file] = info;
         resolve(contents)
       });
    });
  });

  return Promises.all(promises);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copied from comments:

> Also - you might want to use [`fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra), a drop-in replacement for `fs`, but with promise support added.

Here's how that goes:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
var readFiles = ()=>{
  let promises = files
    .map(file => path.resolve(componentPath, file))
    .map(path => fs.readFile(path));
  return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Nice and clean. You can then get contents like this:

```
readFiles()
.then(contents => { ... })
.catch(error => { ... });
```

This will fail on first error though (because that's what `Promise.all` does). If you want individual error handling, you can add another `map` line:

```
.map(promise => promise.catch(err => err));
```

Then you can filter the results:

```
let errors = contents.filter(content => content instanceof Error)
let successes = contents.filter(content => !(content instanceof Error))
```